Laravel Lumen Migration 9-10 Router::middleware() Error
I want to migrate Laravel Lumen from 9 to 10. The composer updated perfectly. But the application is not running and the error comes

"Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::middleware()"

Previously when I migrated from Laravel Lumen 8 to 10 simal error occurred and that we resolved by adding "laravel/passport": "^10.4", but this time the error is not getting fix even after changing the version of laravel/passport to 11,12 etc.
This is my composer.json dependencies.

